# why can't I insert new rows in sqLite?

Tags: android

I am learning SQLite with developer.android.
I created this class like developer.android:

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";
public static final String sakht="CREATE TABLE english (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,kalame TEXT,mani TEXT,marhale TEXT,taghir TEXT";
public static final String pak="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS english";
public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sakht);
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
    // to simply to discard the data and start over
    db.execSQL(pak);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

}
```

I wrote the insert method like developer.android too.

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Date now=new Date();
    values.put("ID", 1);
    values.put("kalame", "hello");
    values.put("mani", "salam");
    values.put("marhale", "1");
    values.put("taghir", now.getTime()+"");

long newRowID=db.insert("english", "taghir" , values);
```

but my app will be force closed
how can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot to call db.open()

Comment: Deleted my answer as long as it was wrong. If you put stacktrace in here I'll try to be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create Query is wrong. try the below code

```
public static final String sakht="CREATE TABLE english (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, kalame TEXT, mani TEXT, marhale TEXT, taghir TEXT);";
```

And your put should be - values.put("taghir", String.valueOf(now.getTime()));